# Does Replica Set in Shard Cluster only stores a "Sharded Copy" or "All Sharded" Copies?

Tags: mongodb

I understand the idea of Replica Set and am able to pull Replica Set Setup by using 3 server, the logic is as below, the reference are from this link https://severalnines.com/database-blog/turning-mongodb-replica-set-sharded-cluster :

[image]

So I came to have confusion when I am trying to understand how does Sharded Cluster works in Replica Logic, the reference I was able to find is as below:

[image]

There are a few concerns:

1. Does Shard 1's Primary only hold 33% of datas?
2. Does Shard 1's Secondary (Replica) hold the data from Shard 2's Primary and Shard 3's Primary?
3. I can see "mongos" knows the Shard 1, Shard 2 and Shard 3 location, then what is the use of mongod config?
4. Is the logic of server placement as below?:

[image]

Comment: For a sharded collection, the data is stored on a shard depending upon the _shard key_ - that is how data is distributed. So, in the above configuration, a shard can store _upto_ 1/3rd of the total data in the sharded collection. For unsharded collection in a sgarded cluster all the collection data is stored on a Primary Shard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does Shard 1's Primary only hold 33% of datas?

Yes, it does - provided your database and collection have "sharding enabled".

2. Does Shard 1's Secondary (Replica) hold the data from Shard 2's Primary and Shard 3's Primary?

No, they don't. Shard 1's Secondaries hold a copy of Shard 1's Primary data.

3. I can see "mongos" knows the Shard 1, Shard 2 and Shard 3 location, then what is the use of mongod config?

The config replica set stores all kind of meta data, e.g. user accounts and privileges and - very important - it stores which ranges of data are stored in which shard. Otherwise, when you insert or read any data, you would not know to which shard they belong to.

Comment: Hi, can you check if the logic of number 4 is correct? In-term of server placement

Comment: In terms of availability, the config mongod should be also installed at server 1,2,3.

Comment: Yes, the logic will work, however in terms of load sharing, performance or scalability you will not gain anything. In total, each server will still contain **all** the data. The idea of sharding is to distribute the data to several servers.